# Why does SQL Server lock SELECT with a different key range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I have two transactions that start one after another:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRANSACTION
select * from MyTable WITH (XLOCK) WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Second one is almost the same (just no delay and another id)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRANSACTION
select * from MyTable WITH (XLOCK) WHERE Id = 2
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I do have a non-unique index on Id. It does seem that this work as expected when there is a primary key on Id at least.

From what I understand the first transaction should really obtain a key-range lock for the Id = 1, while the other should obtain a key-range lock for id 2.

Apparently it does not work like that since the transaction two is stuck until the first one completes. Do I miss something here or I cannot force an exclusive key-range lock?

Here is the full create script for my example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Is `Id` a clustered primary key? What SQL Server version?

Comment: Last Sql server version (Azure Database), It is a clustered primary key, though I'd like that to work with a non-clustered index that is a bit more complex an includes 2 columns (with key-lock like `id = 1 and time > now` e.g.)

Comment: I can't reproduce with a primary key on `Id`, clustered or nonclustered. Can you verify the index on Id exists? It doesn't necessarily need to be the PK as long as it's unique.

Comment: My index won't be unique, does it have to be? I can double-check the primary index from the example

Comment: I have double checked: Id is a primary key on the table, copied the examples from SO into Management Studio and can reproduce each time, there is perhaps something else that can affect this? Perhaps other fields that I have can affect it?

Comment: Can you add the MyTable table DDL to your question, including constraints and indexes?

Comment: And when doing this kind of testing it's a good practice to add `if @@trancount > 0 rollback` to the top of your test batch to guarantee you don't have locks held over from a previous run.

Comment: I tried to use `select * from sys.dm_tran_locks` to check that there is nothing there, would it be the same @DavidBrowne-Microsoft?

Comment: Yes. I often also include `select * from sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id = @@spid` to dump the current for the session.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have reproduced it on the simplest example, I have added it to the question.

Comment: Hmm, still can't repro on my side with a 2 row table. Run `select * from sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id IN(<session-1>,<session-2>)` from a third session to see the granted and waiting locks. Guessing it may be database setting related but I can't think what it would be with the explict transaction isolation level.

Comment: I have tested on an empty table, and I see 2 locks: RangeX-X, one WAIT, one GRANT, both with resource description (ffffffffffff)

Comment: Try it with the 2 rows in your question, 1 and 2.

Comment: That actually works as expected, strangely enough, should not it be a lock that is independent? Let me try with another more complex example without a unique index (the one that I need actually)

Comment: It does not work with a non-unique index unfortunately, I will expand the question. Should not key-range index work in this case? Or maybe sql is smart enough to extend to the whole table when there is very little data perhaps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand the first transaction should really obtain a
> key-range lock for the Id = 1, while the other should obtain a
> key-range lock for id 2.

A key-range lock is taken either way, a range has lower&upper boundaries and the type of index (unique or non-unique) defines the values/limits for the two boundaries:

Assuming, a query for existing values of the index (like in the question, id=1 & id=2),
when index is:

**Unique** : lower key-range boundary = upper key-range boundary = index/row value

**Non-unique** : lower range boundary = index/row value & upper range boundary= next value of index (if any).

When index is unique, the first query selects Id=1 and this locks exclusively (XLOCK) the key-range from index_value = 1 to index_value=1.
The second query, for Id=2, can select the row, because Id=2 is not locked.

When index is non-unique, the first query (Id=1) locks exclusively the key range from index_value = 1 to index_value=2.
The second query (for Id=2) can not select the row since Id=2 is locked (exclusively) by the first query.

If the table had a third row, with values 3..5..10, then a second query selecting any of these values would work just fine, because the key-range lock is from Id 1 to 2.

```
create table mytable(Id bigint not null, index idxId /*unique*/ nonclustered (id));
go
insert into mytable(Id) values (1), (2), (5), (7), (20), (21), (22);
go


set transaction isolation level serializable;
begin transaction
select * from mytable with(xlock) where id = 1;

--nonunique index: rangeXX, 
--........locked values: 1&2 for select...Id=1
--........locked values: 2&5 for select...Id=2
select tl.request_mode, tl.request_type, tl.request_status, tl.resource_description, irs.*
from
sys.dm_tran_locks as tl 
left join
(
select %%lockres%% as idxresourcedescription, Id as [column:Id/value]
from mytable with (index(idxId), nolock)
) as irs
on tl.resource_description = irs.idxresourcedescription;

--rollback transaction
go


--in another session/window
select * from mytable with(xlock, serializable) where id = 5; --this is not blocked...
raiserror('', 0, 0) with nowait;
select * from mytable with(xlock, serializable) where id = 2; --...but this is blocked
go
```

It gets slightly more "complicated" to assess the range locks when trying to select  (exclusively&serializable) a value that does not exist (as you have noticed, in your comment, about the (ffffffffffff) range lock).

In the example/code above, selecting Id=34, which does not exist, will lock the range Id= 22 - ∞ (max range of datatype). A second query (in another session) trying to select Id = 25 will be blocked (because it needs to lock the range 22 - ∞ too).
sys.dm_tran_locks or sp_lock will report only one value(upper boundary) for the keyrange : (ffffffffffff)==∞. The lower boundary (inferred?) = max(id).

Accourdingly, selecting Id=-20 will lock the keyrange [-∞] - 1 and sys.dm_tran_locks reports one boundary (Id=1). The lower boundary (inferred) = [-∞].

You could try and guesstimate, the keyrange lock when table has Ids (7), (20) and a query selects Id=15 (with a nonunique and/or unique index). Conceptually, in serializable transaction there is a keyrange lock and locks need to be taken on existing keys/values (there is no row with Id=15, locks have to be on different keys/values).

Comment: Thanks for a really good and comprehensive answer! That does really clarify how it works. It always blocks what is required, but can block more in different circumstances as a collateral damage in a way. It is acceptable in my scenario actually, but I'd try to use sp_getapplock to block the resource I need myself (i have a logical id I can use per operation). I will then not use an exclusive lock for SELECT but rather obtain an application lock. Do you know if there are some troubles that I can expect compared to serializable transaction level + exclusive lock?