# WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) and NON-unique index - does it lock a whole table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below with NON-unique index on the regionId column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Localizations]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [regionId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Localizations] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RegionId_index] 
ON [dbo].[Localizations] ([regionId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
               ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am executing the following query:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM [dbo].[Localizations] WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
                  WHERE regionId = 1)
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Localizations] 
        VALUES ('aa', 1);
    END;
COMMIT;
```

And in the meanwhile the following query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Localizations]
SET name = 'bb'
WHERE regionid = 2
```

The second query waits till the first query ends. If I change the non-unique index of `regionId` column to the unique index of `regionId` column then the second query executes immediately. :O Why??

Does it mean the non-unique index of the `regionId` column together with `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` locks a whole table?

Comment: holdlock is equivalent to serializable isolation level…  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931837/why-does-sql-server-lock-select-with-a-different-key-range/64958569#64958569

Comment: @lptr wow - thank you for this explanation, amazing - update for the row with regionId = 3 and non-unique index executes immediately - wow

Comment: …@user2017341 ..    ….